# Jenkins - how to schedule and instantly fail build programmatically

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

What is the correct way to schedule the build and then fail it instantly? And I need to see this build in history.

```
QueueTaskFuture<?> queueTaskFuture = project.scheduleBuild2(someQuietTime, someCause);
queueTaskFuture.cancel(true);
```

This solution doesn't allow build to be added to history. I tried with quietTime = 0 also. Any ideas?

I was thinking about adding a custom `Builder` that can check some conditions and fail the build if necessary (like it's implemented in [Fail The Build Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/fail-the-build-plugin/)) but maybe there is some easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
throw new hudson.AbortException("Cancelled");
```

For details see: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/AbortException.html

Comment: From where I can throw it? I don't need to fail current executing build, I need to schedule a new one and fail it immediately.